# How to encode a text field value to HEX in Flutter

Tags: flutter, encoding, hex

I have the following code to enter a text into a textfield, on the `onChanged()` I can see the value entered in HEX.But when I'm trying to print the value of `hexString` on the `onPressed()` it is empty.I need to include this value on the async to send it in a API request.Any help is appreciated.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:australremote/screens/screen4.dart';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _textController = TextEditingController();

  final String title = '';
  final String subtitle = '';



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as List<String>;
String ssid =  args[0];
String auth =  args[1];
String hexString = '';


    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Your selected SSID is :$ssid"),
            Text("Your authentication is :$auth"),
            TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter the password of your Wifi network"),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  hexString = '';
                  for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    hexString += value[i].codeUnitAt(0).toRadixString(16);
                    print(hexString);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),


            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                // You can get the entered text using the text controller
                String enteredText = _textController.text;

print(enteredText);
print(hexString);


                // Send the text to the API using the http package
                final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
                  "http://10.10.10.254/httpapi.asp?command=wlanConnectApEx:ssid=$ssid:ch=1:auth=$auth:encry=AES:pwd=$enteredText:chext=1"),

                );
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {

                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                } else {
                  // There was an error with the request
                  // You can handle the error here
                }
              },
              child: Text("Connect"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have defined `hexString` *within* your `build` method, so every `setState` it gets reset:

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as List<String>;
    ...
    String hexString = '';
```

Instead, define `hexString` in your `_state` class:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _textController = TextEditingController();

  final String title = '';
  final String subtitle = '';
  hexString = ''; // <-- Define it here
```

Comment: When I set the hexString outside the build method it duplicates each keystroke of text entered when I'm printing it on the onChanged()

Comment: When I set the hexString outside the build method it duplicates each keystroke of text entered when I'm printing it on the onChanged()

Answer (score 0):

The reason that happened is that you define `hexString` and other variable inside `build` method, and every time you call `setState` , it reset `hexString` and set empty value to it, just define those variable out of build method and pass its value in initState, like this:

```
List<String> args = [];
String ssid = "";
String auth =  "";
String hexString = '';

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as List<String>;
  ssid =  args[0];
  auth =  args[1];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(

  ...
  );
}
```